# first selected option in selectizeInput overwriting plot output so that only one variable plots instead of multiple in radar plot

Tags: r, shiny, radar-chart

I'm trying to create a radar plot that I can select multiple inputs on (cultivars) and plot 3 together. However, it seems my code causes the first selected option to overwrite any additional selections. I think, perhaps, a loop is needed but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

For example, based on each selected input I define the dataset that will be plotted as "new" but don't know how to approach this to make it so that there can be multiple selections.

```
library(shiny)
library(fmsb)

aroma<-data.frame(
  aroma = c(15.0, 0.0, 1.2, 1.8, 2.0, 2.6, 2.8, 1.1, 1.2, 2.6, 1.0, 2.7, 1.7, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.6, 2.4),
  leaf_size = c(15.0, 0.0, 4.6, 6.1, 4.5, 5.6, 6.5, 8.1, 6.6, 6.6, 2.6, 2.5, 2.4,5.5, 6.1, 7.5, 8.0, 7.3),
  red_stems_and_leaves = c(15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 5.8, 7.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ,0.0, 1.1, 0.0, 3.6, 12.8),
  leaf_homogeneity = c(15.0, 0.0, 13.3, 10.8, 0.0, 11.0, 11.0, 9.9, 12.0, 11.7, 13.1, 11.4, 12.0, 12.5, 10.1, 13.4, 12.0, 13.0),
  leaf_yellowing = c(15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
  color_intensity = c(15.0, 0.0, 5.1, 8.7, 7.4, 8.9, 7.1, 3.9, 8.8, 5.5, 7.0, 6.5, 5.6, 7.6, 6.7, 6.6, 7.2, 14.0),
  hardness = c(15.0, 0.0, 1.8, 4.4, 3.5, 2.6, 3.0, 2.9, 3.3, 2.8, 2.2, 3.0, 2.3, 2.6, 2.0, 3.9, 3.3, 2.2),
  crispness = c(15.0, 0.0, 2.9, 5.0, 4.0, 7.9, 3.5, 4.0, 3.9, 4.0, 4.6, 5.9, 4.8, 4.8, 4.5, 5.0, 5.0, 2.5),
  fibrousness = c(15.0, 0.0, 3.1, 2.6, 3.1, 3.0, 2.1, 2.8, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 1.5, 3.6, 3.0, 2.9),
  moisture_release = c(15.0, 0.0, 3.5, 3.1, 3.1, 2.5, 2.0, 3.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.1, 2.9, 3.9, 4.0, 3.8, 2.3, 2.0, 2.0), 
  row.names = c("max", "min", "Sorrel", "Cabbage, Red", "Kohlrabi, Purple", "Mustard, Garnet Giant", "Arugula", 
                "Pac Choi, Tokyo Bekana", "Kale, Toscano", "Mustard, Green Wave", "Tatsoi", "Mizuna, Central Red","Mustard, Wasabina", 
                "Broccoli", "Kale, Red Russian", "Radish, Daikon", "Radish, Hong Vit", "Radish, Red Rambo"))


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Rename"),

    # Sidebar 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput("cultivar",
                            "Select Cultivars:",
                            choices = c("Sorrel", "Cabbage, Red", "Kohlrabi, Purple", "Mustard, Garnet Giant", "Arugula",
                                        "Pac Choi, Tokyo Bekana", "Kale, Toscano", "Mustard, Green Wave", "Tatsoi", "Mizuna, Central Red","Mustard, Wasabina",
                                        "Broccoli", "Kale, Red Russian", "Radish, Daikon", "Radish, Hong Vit", "Radish, Red Rambo"),
                            selected = "Sorrel",
                            multiple = TRUE)
        ),

        # Show a plot
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("plot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$cultivar == "Sorrel") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 3), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Cabbage, Red") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 4), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Kohlrabi, Purple") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 5), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Mustard, Garnet Giant") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 6), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Arugula") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 7), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Pac Choi, Tokyo Bekana") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 8), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Kale, Toscano") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 9), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Mustard, Green Wave") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 10), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Tatsoi") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 11), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Mizuna, Central Red") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 12), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Mustard, Wasabina") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 13), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Broccoli") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 14), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Kale, Red Russian") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 15), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Radish, Daikon") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 16), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Radish, Hong Vit") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 17), ]
    }
    if (input$cultivar == "Radish, Red Rambo") {
      new <- aroma[c(1:2, 18), ]
      
    }
    
    radarchart(new,
               seg = 20,
               title = input$variable1,
               # pcol = colors_line,
               # pfcol = colors_fill,
               plwd = 1
    )
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. You don't need to use all the `if` statements; instead, check which elements in `row.names` match the choices.

```
library(shiny)
library(fmsb)

aroma<-data.frame(
  aroma = c(15.0, 0.0, 1.2, 1.8, 2.0, 2.6, 2.8, 1.1, 1.2, 2.6, 1.0, 2.7, 1.7, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.6, 2.4),
  leaf_size = c(15.0, 0.0, 4.6, 6.1, 4.5, 5.6, 6.5, 8.1, 6.6, 6.6, 2.6, 2.5, 2.4,5.5, 6.1, 7.5, 8.0, 7.3),
  red_stems_and_leaves = c(15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 5.8, 7.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ,0.0, 1.1, 0.0, 3.6, 12.8),
  leaf_homogeneity = c(15.0, 0.0, 13.3, 10.8, 0.0, 11.0, 11.0, 9.9, 12.0, 11.7, 13.1, 11.4, 12.0, 12.5, 10.1, 13.4, 12.0, 13.0),
  leaf_yellowing = c(15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
  color_intensity = c(15.0, 0.0, 5.1, 8.7, 7.4, 8.9, 7.1, 3.9, 8.8, 5.5, 7.0, 6.5, 5.6, 7.6, 6.7, 6.6, 7.2, 14.0),
  hardness = c(15.0, 0.0, 1.8, 4.4, 3.5, 2.6, 3.0, 2.9, 3.3, 2.8, 2.2, 3.0, 2.3, 2.6, 2.0, 3.9, 3.3, 2.2),
  crispness = c(15.0, 0.0, 2.9, 5.0, 4.0, 7.9, 3.5, 4.0, 3.9, 4.0, 4.6, 5.9, 4.8, 4.8, 4.5, 5.0, 5.0, 2.5),
  fibrousness = c(15.0, 0.0, 3.1, 2.6, 3.1, 3.0, 2.1, 2.8, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 1.5, 3.6, 3.0, 2.9),
  moisture_release = c(15.0, 0.0, 3.5, 3.1, 3.1, 2.5, 2.0, 3.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.1, 2.9, 3.9, 4.0, 3.8, 2.3, 2.0, 2.0), 
  row.names = c("max", "min", "Sorrel", "Cabbage, Red", "Kohlrabi, Purple", "Mustard, Garnet Giant", "Arugula", 
                "Pac Choi, Tokyo Bekana", "Kale, Toscano", "Mustard, Green Wave", "Tatsoi", "Mizuna, Central Red","Mustard, Wasabina", 
                "Broccoli", "Kale, Red Russian", "Radish, Daikon", "Radish, Hong Vit", "Radish, Red Rambo"))


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Rename"),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("cultivar",
                     "Select Cultivars:",
                     choices = row.names(aroma)[-(1:2)],
                     selected = "Sorrel",
                     multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    
    # Show a plot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  selectedVar <- reactive({
    input$cultivar 
  })
  
  newDf <- reactive({
    # check which elements in row.names match the choices
      g1 <- apply(sapply(X = selectedVar(), FUN = grepl, row.names(aroma)), MARGIN =  1, FUN = any)

      addedDf <- aroma[c(1:2, which(g1)), ] # this is the "new" with (multiple) selections
      
      return(addedDf)
 
    })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    radarchart(newDf(),
               seg = 20,
               title = input$variable1,
               # pcol = colors_line,
               # pfcol = colors_fill,
               plwd = 1
    )
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi @bdedu, thank you for this help, this code makes sense to me though it seems I'm finding another error in running it which is: "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'".

Comment: Oops, I used `row.names` directly instead of `row.names(aroma)`. Now the code is modified and it should work.

Comment: Aha! It goes, thank you so much for your help!